# Retrofit 2 POST запрос в форме JSON

Tags: android, retrofit

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно в Retrofit 2 отправить POST запрос в формате JSON?
Запрос следующий:

```
{
    datetime: 0,
    body: {
    gymId: '3422342342423424',
    customerName: 'test',
    customerEmail: 'test@test.ru',
    content: 'test'
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/square/retrofit/q/stackoverflow/21398598/how-to-post-raw-whole-json-in-the-body-of-a-retrofit-request

Answer (score 3):

Я использую для этих целей LoganSquare.

Подключаешь в gradle LoganSquare и LoganSquareConverter (com.github.aurae.retrofit2:converter-logansquare:1.4.0').

После создаешь модели:

Для запроса:

```
@JsonObject
public class Request{

@JsonField(name = "datetime")
int datetime;
@JsonField(name = "body")
Model body;


/* тут создаешь пустой конструктор и конструктор для всех переменных*/ 
}
```

Вспомогательная:

```
@JsonObject
public class Model{

@JsonField(name = "gymId")
String gymId;
@JsonField(name = "customerName")
String customerName;
@JsonField(name = "customerEmail")
String customerEmail;
@JsonField(name = "content")
String content;

/* тут создаешь пустой конструктор и конструктор для всех переменных*/ 
}
```

Далее в Retorfit интерфейсе описываешь метод:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST(/*url метода (допустим "/mymetod"*/)
Call myMetod(@Body Request body);
```

Далее выполняешь сам запрос:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(/*BASE URL "например 192.168.1.1:6666"*/)
            .addConverterFactory(LoganSquareConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);  
       Call<Request> call = service.myMetod(/* тут создаешь модель*/ new Request(0, new Model("1235464", "test", "test@test.ru", "test"));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MarketResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Request> call, Response<Request> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Request> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```